Удаление товара YITH Wishlist
Возникла проблема в удалении товара из "Избранных" с помощью плагина YITH Wishlist
Файл content-product.php
<?php if(YITH_WCWL()->is_product_in_wishlist($product->get_ID())):?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_from_wishlist', $product->get_ID(), $base_url ), 'remove_from_wishlist' ) ); ?>"
                class="delete_item <?php echo esc_attr( $link_classes ); ?> card__favorite card__favorite_set"
                data-item-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $found_item->get_id() ); ?>"
                data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>"
                data-original-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $parent_product_id ); ?>"
                data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist_title', $label ) ); ?>"
                rel="nofollow">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-favorite"></use>
                </svg>
            </a>
            <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'add_to_wishlist', $product->get_ID(), $base_url ), 'add_to_wishlist' ) ); ?>"
                class="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_classes ); ?> card__favorite yith-wcwl-add-button"
                data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>"
                data-product-type="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_type ); ?>"
                data-original-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $parent_product_id ); ?>"
                data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist_title', $label ) ); ?>"
                rel="nofollow">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-favorite"></use>
                </svg>
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

Ругается на $found_item->get_id(), так как она не определена.
Как ее получить? Спасибо!

А если после первой строки (if....) добавить:
$wishlist = YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist();
$found_item = $wishlist->get_product_by_id($product_id);

